# How to run java class file which is in different directory?

Tags: java, class

Directory path:

```
c:\home\test\src\com\bsoft\conc
```

I have my java program in `src` folder  and I have my class file in `conc` folder. 
I need to run my java program from `home` folder.When I run I'm getting error:

```
could not find or load main class
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've compiled your `.java` files into `.class` files...?

Comment: What classpath did you use?

Comment: Show how do you call the program!

Comment: you could use .jar file and use the class in your current application

Comment: You didn't state what you tried. However `java -classpath c:\home\test\src com.bsoft.conc.MyClass` should work, substituting your real class name for `MyClass` of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my program **com.bsoft.conc** is a package name where my class file for the compiled program will be stored.If I have to run that from *home* folder we have to specify 
**java -classpath test\src  com.bsoft.conc."class-file-name"**

This is because we need to tell the JVM where it has to look for class file.

so , we have to specify navigation to the src using *"test\src"* and then 
class file location *"com.bsoft.conc.class-file-name"*

If you have set environment variable in advanced settings then it will also be overriden if you specify classpath in cmd

Answer (score 11):

Set your class path for this java file:

```
java -cp C:\hello\build\classes com.javahowto.test.HelloWorld
```

or using Environment variables and run it from any third location from that machine.

Answer (score 6):

It's time for you to read on about `classpath` ( a way to tell java compiler where to look for the class file you intend to run ). 
Basically there are two ways to set classpath

1. a environment variable CLASSPATH having ':' separate directories in unix and ';' separated directories in windows
2. `-classpath` or `-cp` command line arg to `javac` command

Refer and read the below links completely
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I was trying to run a Java program that calls a method in a class that is in another directory. I read this page and added the directory to my classpath, but I made the mistake of using '*~*' which in Bash means '*/home/user/*'.

So this command did NOT work

> java -classpath ~/CurrentDirectory:OtherDirectory program

But this command did

> java -classpath /home/user/CurrentDirectory:OtherDirectory program

Answer (score 1):

The answers here don't touch on the spaces problem.

If your path has spaces, **you must wrap it inside the quotes**, otherwise an error would show up:

```
C:
 Program Files
    MyProject
       src
         testpackage
             Test.java
       target
         classes
             testpackage
                 Test.class
```

```
package testpackage;

public class Test  {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("Test");
  }
}
```

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\MyProject\target\classes" testpackage.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux ( Simple scenario with out consider them as packages )

```
   > parent
         |
         |- stdlib
         |      |
         |      -Library.java
         |- Main.java
```

COMPILE FROM PARENT >  javac -cp ./stdlib: Main.java

RUN FROM PARENT     >  java -cp ./stdlib: Main