# How can I use downloaded Github libraries in my own program?

Tags: java, git, github, libraries, wav

I'm writing a program that draws a waveform when given a .wav file but I want it to work for .mp3's as well. Since the java.sound package doesn't support .mp3 files I found a github program that converts an mp3 file to a .wav file. I downloaded the project and got this:

[image]

Now theres a class in this project that I'm particularly interested in and thats the WaveConverter class. It's fairly simple and asks for the input .mp3 file and the output of what you would like to convert it to. This is what it looks like:

```
package org.mp3transform.wav;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.mp3transform.Bitstream;
import org.mp3transform.Decoder;
import org.mp3transform.Header;

public class WavConverter extends Decoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String in = "test.mp3";
    String out = "out.wav";
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if ("-in".equals(args[i])) {
            in = args[++i];
        } else if ("-in".equals(args[i])) {
            out = args[++i];
        } else {
            System.out.println("Options: -in <input.mp3> -out <output.wav>");
        }
    }
    WavConverter.convert(in, out);
}

private static void convert(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
        throws IOException {
    System.out.println(sourceFileName);
    InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sourceFileName);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn, 128 * 1024);
    convert(in, destFileName);
    in.close();
}

private static void convert(InputStream sourceStream, String destFileName)
        throws IOException {
    int frameCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    WavConverter decoder = new WavConverter();
    Bitstream stream = new Bitstream(sourceStream);
    frameCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    try {
        for (int frame = 0; frame < frameCount; frame++) {
            Header header = stream.readFrame();
            if (header == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (decoder.channels == 0) {
                int channels = (header.mode() == Header.MODE_SINGLE_CHANNEL) ? 1
                        : 2;
                int freq = header.frequency();
                decoder.initOutputBuffer(channels, freq, destFileName);
            }
            decoder.decodeFrame(header, stream);
            stream.closeFrame();
        }
    } finally {
        decoder.close();
    }
}

private short[] buffer;
private WaveFileWriter outWave;

public void initOutputBuffer(int numberOfChannels, int freq, String fileName)
        throws IOException {
    super.initOutputBuffer(null, numberOfChannels);
    buffer = new short[BUFFER_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; ++i) {
        bufferPointer[i] = (short) i;
    }
    outWave = new WaveFileWriter(fileName, freq, (short) 16,
            (short) numberOfChannels);
}

public void appendSamples(int channel, double[] f) {
    int p = bufferPointer[channel];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        double sample = f[i];
        short s = ((sample > 32767.0f) ? 32767
                : ((sample < -32768.0f) ? -32768 : (short) sample));
        buffer[p] = s;
        p += 2;
    }
    bufferPointer[channel] = p;
}    

public void writeBuffer() throws IOException {
    outWave.writeData(buffer, bufferPointer[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < channels; ++i) {
        bufferPointer[i] = i;
    }
 }

 public void close() throws IOException {
    outWave.close();
 }
}
```

However my problem is that I keep getting a FileNotFoundException for line 50 which is the following line of code:

InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sourceFileName);

For some reason the program is not able to find my test.mp3 file even though as you can see from this picture, it is clearly in the same directory:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a better way to use classes from github projects? I'm really confused and would love the help. Thanks.

Comment: Show the exception. Show the exact file name from that exception. Show how you ran the program and especially what is the working directory for it.

Comment: you don't have `test.mp3` in your project so... so if you try to load up this class out of context it bonks.

Comment: @kpie If you look at the image I do have test.mp3. It's an mp3 file I got to test the conversion.

Comment: @slaw No i'm not sure. The program initially had "in.mp3" for the String in variable and I changed it to "test.mp3". I then found a random mp3 file and named it to "test.mp3" to see if it would work. I placed "test.mp3" in the same directory as the WavConverter class and ran WavConverter since it has a main method but as I stated I'm getting a FileNotFoundException. Is this not an appropriate way to test it?

Comment: @kpie Ok thad makes sense. So if I shouldn't hard code it, how can I use my program to pass it the name of the .mp3 file I would like to convert?

Comment: @Slaw I did this and it gives the following compilation error:     
                                                              
   WavConverter.main(args[0], args[1]);
    ^
  bad source file: .\WavConverter.java
    file does not contain class WavConverter
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error

Comment: I'm confused because I put it in the working directory of my test program. Its not giving me a "can't find symbol error" but instead a bad source file error. What would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

the path `test.mp3` is a path relative to the directory from which you run your program.

2 ways to solve your problem:

- In `WavConverter.java` you define the full path of your mp3 file: `C: \ .. \ .. \ ..... \ test.mp3`
- You define the classpath for WavConverter. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237345/how-to-run-java-class-file-which-is-in-different-directory/25238371) an example

Hope this helps.