# Why doesn't for loop work in java makefile?

Tags: java, makefile

I tried running an unspecified number of tests using a makefile, tested the command beforehand in bash but when I try it from the makefile it doesn't work. All it does in vscode is write the code I typed a bit modified back to me and in itelliJ even the make and clean rules don't work. The rule I'm referring to is run-p1.

```
make:
    javac ./src/Bucket.java ./src/Graph.java ./src/ShortestPath.java ./src/Weight.java

run-p1:
    tests=$$(ls ./in | grep -E "test[0-9]+.in")
    for i in $$tests; do\
        java ./src/ShortestPath.class 1 "$$i";\
    done

clean:
    rm ./src/*.class
```

For testing all I did in ShortestPath.java main is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String s: args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: “Don’t work” means?

Comment: In what millenium was a Makefile a good way to build/run Java projects?  Answer: none. Makefiles are ancient, and they don't support Java best practices, like dependency management.  I strongly suggest using Gradle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run java class file which is in different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237345/how-to-run-java-class-file-which-is-in-different-directory)

Comment: I need to use a makefile because my university demands it... So in that matter I have no choice. As for "don't work" I mean they do nothing, when I type make It doesn't compile anything and make clean doesn't delete any files (in vscode they both work, the problem is with intelliJ)...

Comment: Assuming you're using `GNU make`, each line in the `make` recipe is executed (by default) in its own shell.  So the line `tests=$$(ls ./in | grep -E "test[0-9]+.in")` does *not* set `tests` for the following lines.

Comment: So what can I do to get the list of test files so I can run the program for each one when I don't know how many of them are?

Comment: Add a backslash.  So `tests=$$(ls ./in | grep -E "test[0-9]+.in") \ `.  There's probably a good dupe for this.

Comment: You should add a `;` and backslash, not just backslash.  Note, this is not specific to GNU make: every POSIX-style make program behaves this way.

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding ;\ to tests=$$(ls ./in | grep -E "test[0-9]+.in") like you said and running ShortestPath instead of ShortestPath.class. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the correction: forgot about the semicolon.